# HTML file exported to Excel giving error "File is moved or deleted"

Tags: html, excel, jsp, download

We have few HTML table reports which are exported as excel by setting the content type. Recently we have started facing issue in IE 11 (Windows 7) where we get error "File is moved or deleted" on trying to download. Retrying the download solves the issue at some instances. But since this is a bug, this has to be fixed.

Note: We are adding header X-UA-Compatible  IE=EmulateIE9 for our site.

Comment: Does this happen only in your website, or in all webpages where file can be downloaded?

Comment: Not all the sites, some sites only mainly our internal site